# Merge function not working for a single record

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am currently learning pandas. For an assignment I have to merge to dataframes. This is succesful for the top 15 records I need, except for one, which is Iran. When I do an 'outer' merge, it presents me this:

```
+---------+-------+------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+---------------------------+--------------+---------------+
|         | Rank  | Documents  | Citable documents  | Citations  | Self-citations  | Citations per document  | H index  | Energy Supply  | Energy Supply per Capita  | % Renewable  |     2006      |
+---------+-------+------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+---------------------------+--------------+---------------+
| Country |       |            |                    |            |                 |                         |          |                |                           |              |               |
| Iran    | 13.0  | 8896.0     | 8819.0             | 57470.0    | 19125.0         | 6.46                    | 72.0     | NaN            | NaN                       | NaN          | 3.895523e+11  |
| Iran    | NaN   | NaN        | NaN                | NaN        | NaN             | NaN                     | NaN      | 9172000000     | 119.0                     | 5.707721     | NaN           |
+---------+-------+------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+---------------------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I actually want an 'inner' merge, but then no results for Iran are shown. What could be the cause that the two Iran records are not merged?

This is how I merge:

```
combined2 = pd.merge(combined1, energy, how='outer', on='Country')
```

The `combined1` dataframe is from another merge, which I checked and which contains a single record for Iran. This is how I created the `energy` dataframe:

```
country_dict = {"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
           "United States of America": "United States",
           "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
           "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong",
           "Korea, Rep.": "South Korea", 
           "Iran, Islamic Rep.": "Iran",
           "Hong Kong SAR, China": "Hong Kong"}

def convert_county_name(name):
    name = re.sub("\(.*\)", "", name)
    name = re.sub("[0-9]", "", name)
    for k, v in country_dict.items():
        name = name.replace(k, v)
    return name

en_converters = {1 : lambda x: x * 1000000 if isinstance(x, numbers.Number) else x,
                 0 : convert_county_name}
energy = pd.read_excel("Energy Indicators.xls", 
                      skiprows = 17, 
                      skip_footer = 38, 
                      parse_cols = [2,3,4,5], 
                      names = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', 
                               '% Renewable'],
                      na_values="...",
                      converters = en_converters)
```

Comment: It seems value `Iran` is duplicated, the best is use for testing some small data sample. Or another possible problem is some whitespaces like `'Iran '` and `'Iran'`

Comment: How stupid! I ruled the whitespaces out, because in the Jupyter table they didn't show, however when I printed the specific element, there was indeed a whitespace after `'Iran '`

Comment: Ya, this type of error is very hard find, if do you not meet it before ...

Comment: Lesson learned! :D

Comment: Yes, the nice is if similar problem you check whitespaces ;) Nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `convert_country_name` function to remove whitespaces:

```
def convert_county_name(name):
    name = re.sub("\(.*\)", "", name)
    name = re.sub("[0-9]", "", name)
    for k, v in country_dict.items():
        name = name.replace(k, v)
    name = name.strip()
    return name
```